# pygame not drawing lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Whenever I run the program, the pygame screen will open straight away. I  am trying to get the pygame screen to open once the user input has been completed, however if I change the position of `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))`, the program will not draw any lines anymore. Is there a way to have the screen open only once the user input has been collected?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

gray = (100,100,100)
lightgray = (200,200,200)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

p = [] #empty points array
#gets 4 control points from user input
def get_points():
    #loops through 4 times to get 4 control points
    for i in range(4):
        while True:
            #user input
            p_input = input("Enter X,Y Coordinates for p" + str(i) + ":")
            #splits the string into x and y coordinates
            p_components = p_input.split(',')
            #checks to see if user hasnt entered two coordinates
            if len(p_components) != 2:
                print("Missing coordinate please try again.")
                p_input = input("Enter X,Y Coordinates for p" + str(i) + ":")
                p_components = p_input.split(',')
            #checks to see if the values can not be converted into floats
            try:
                x = float(p_components[0])
                y = float(p_components[1])
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid coordinates", p_components, "please try again.")
            #appends the x and y coordinates as a 2 dimensional array
            else:
                p.append([float(p_components[0]), float(p_components[1])])
                break
#gets parameter 't' interval from user input
def get_interval():
    while True: 
        try:
            i = int(input("Please enter an interval for the parameter t:"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid interval, please try again")
        else:
            i = abs(i)
            break
    return i
#calculates required coordinates for plotting bezier curve.
def bezier():
    result = [] #empty result array, which will store values x and y values from the bezier curve equation
    get_points() #gets the 4 control points
    i = get_interval() #gets the parameter 't' interval 
    for x in range(i+1): #i+1 so that it includes the last value
        t = x/i #x/i due to python not being able to have a step value of a float, so this is a work around
        x=(p[0][0]*(1-t)**3+p[1][0]*3*t*(1-t)**2+p[2][0]*3*t**2*(1-t)+p[3][0]*t**3) #calculates x coordinate
        y=(p[0][1]*(1-t)**3+p[1][1]*3*t*(1-t)**2+p[2][1]*3*t**2*(1-t)+p[3][1]*t**3) #calculates y coordinate
        result.append((int(x), int(y))) #appends coordinates to result array.
    return result

def main(): 
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
    points = bezier()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    #draws the control points
    for i in p:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, blue, (int(i[0]), int(i[1])), 4)
    #draws the lines between control points
    pygame.draw.lines(screen, lightgray, False, p)
    #draws the bezier curve
    pygame.draw.lines(screen, pygame.Color("red"), False, points, 2)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(100)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Try to minimize your code for this specific problem (for instance remove the get_points() and replace with dummy coordinates)

Comment: when I use dummy points, the curve is drawn as soon as the program is run, but Its not very ideal, since it should be able to take user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window will be created as soon as you call `pygame.display.set_mode`. If you want to open it after the points are input, call it below `bezier()`.

Also, put your drawing code into a while loop, otherwise you run that code only once and the program will stop afterwards.

```
def main():
    pygame.init()

    points = bezier()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # Close the window by pressing the x button.
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

        #draws the control points
        for i in p:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, blue, (int(i[0]), int(i[1])), 4)
        #draws the lines between control points
        pygame.draw.lines(screen, lightgray, False, p)
        #draws the bezier curve
        pygame.draw.lines(screen, pygame.Color("red"), False, points, 2)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(100)
```